# Как правильно преобразовать OData-запрос в Linq-выражение?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

Экшн на контроллере в WebAPI 2 имеет следующую сигнатуру:

```
async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetModels(ODataQueryOptions<MyDbModel> opts)
```

А метод сервиса, при помощи которого предполагается получать данные, имеет сигнатуру

```
async Task<IEnumerable<MyDbModel>> FindAsync(
     Expression<Func<MyDbModel, bool>> filters, 
     int? take = null, 
     int? skip = null)
```

Уже битый час пытаюсь понять, как правильно преобразовать `ODataQueryOptions<MyDbModel>` в `Expression<Func<MyDbModel, bool>>`. Может есть какие-то сторонние библиотеки, которые позволят это сделать без лишних телодвижений?

Comment: А никак. Одатовский запрос может в себя включать select или expand, даже если предположить что skip и take вы как то прокинете. Готовых бибилиотек я не нашел, но если вам повезет и вы найдете что-то позволяющее например opts.Filter.Where (или как там его) преобразовать в expression обычный - было бы интересно почитать.

Comment: Ну и ещё. Skip и Take могут делаться по каким то полям, ваш сервис может только количественно похоже. Т.е. и это мимо.